# recursive async to promises or callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise

**Problem**: 
I have a tricky situation, I'm recursively traversing files and directories and when a file matches a certain criteria, I read the first line of that file using Node's readLine (async function). Once that line is read and entry gets pushed into a variable (eg. depTree). Since some of my code is async, I'm unable to get the value of depTree synchronously.

**Code**:

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
const readline = require('readline');
const path = './mycoolpath/';
const depTree = [];

const imports = file => {
    const readLines = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(file),
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });
    // read each line, and push line to depTree if it passes my regex criteria
    readLines.on('line', (line) => {
        if (/lineMatchesMyregex/.test(line)) {
            depTree.push(line)
        }
    });
}

const recursiveSearch = path => {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(path);
    for (var i in files) {
        var file = path + '/' + files[i];
        var stats = fs.statSync(file);
        if (stats.isFile()) {
            imports(file);
        }
        else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            recursiveSearch(file);
        }
    }

};

recursiveSearch(path);

//// embaressing setTimeout
// setTimeout(() => {
//     console.log(depTree)
// }, 1000)
```

**Attempts**:

I'm having to use a setTimeout and i'ms sure there is a better way, I've tinkered with callbacks and promises but to no avail. I'd appreciate any help/insight.

Comment: "I'm unable to get the value of depTree synchronously."  Do you mean like, doing something in the end after all directories have been traversed? Are you trying to do execute some time of actions during the process?

Comment: @terary - Yes, it's at the end of the code block (you need to scroll down a bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `async/await` keywords and promises in Node.js, you can tackle this problem as follows:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const path = './mycoolpath/';
const depTree = [];

const imports = file => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const readLines = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(file),
            crlfDelay: Infinity
        });
        // read each line, and push line to depTree if it passes my regex criteria
        readLines.on('line', (line) => {
            if (/lineMatchesMyregex/.test(line)) {
                depTree.push(line)
            }
        });
        // once done reading all the lines, resolve the promise
        readLines.on('close', () => {
            resolve();
        })
    });
}

const recursiveSearch = async (path) => {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(path);
    for (var i in files) {
        var file = path + '/' + files[i];
        var stats = fs.statSync(file);
        if (stats.isFile()) {
            await imports(file);
        } else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            await recursiveSearch(file);
        }
    }

};


//// embaressing setTimeout
setTimeout(async () => {
    await recursiveSearch(path);
    console.log(depTree)
}, 1000)

// or even better, to avoid too long or too short timeout
recursiveSearch(path)
    .then(() => {
        console.log(depTree)
    })
```

Comment: Thank you Behrooz, I'm setting you as the answer, as I tested it and it worked flawlessly and I think it's clean and elegant way of solving this. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Tourshi - Just beware that this serializes the process, whereas before it was parallel (waiting for the I/O operation for one file to complete didn't hold up your other work). Easier to reason about, but may have lower throughput.

Answer (score 1):

You can build an array of promises rather than an array of lines, then use `Promise.all` to wait for them all to resolve (or for any of them to reject). See `***` below:

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
const readline = require('readline');
const path = './mycoolpath/';
const depTreePromises = []; // ***

const imports = file => {
    const readLines = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(file),
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });
    // read each line, and push line to depTree if it passes my regex criteria
    // *** Remember a promise
    depTreePromises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        readLines.on('line', (line) => {
            if (/* can this fail? */) {
                reject(/*...*/);
            } else {
                resolve(/lineMatchesMyregex/.test(line) ? line : null);
            }
            // Side note: `destroy` the stream here? Since there's no need
            // for more lines?
        });
    }));
}

const recursiveSearch = path => {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(path);
    for (var i in files) {
        var file = path + '/' + files[i];
        var stats = fs.statSync(file);
        if (stats.isFile()) {
            imports(file);
        }
        else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            recursiveSearch(file);
        }
    }

};

recursiveSearch(path);

// *** Wait for all, use result
Promise.all(depTreePromises)
    .then(depTree => depTree.filter(n => n !== null)) // Remove the ones that didn't match (can be just `n => n` if blank lines aren't a match for your regex
    .then(depTree => {
        console.log(depTree);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // do something with the error
    });
```

You might also look into use of `async` functions, although if used naively in the above, they'd make the code more serial than it currently is (currently lots of line reading is in parallel, which is good).

Comment: You can use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to create a promise for Node's async functions.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Yeah. I wasn't entirely sure how I'd use it on the readline stuff above, though, so...

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder, really appreciate your help and everyone here. Looks like I need to hit the books some more when it comes to promises!

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: The OP is not having issues with reading files but the a/sync aspects.
I have used 'BUGUTILS.blocker(3)' to mimic the sync file read.

```
results.forEach(result=>{
        console.log("\t",result);
    })
```

Can be substituted for 'finish(...)' or whatever

```
"use strict";

const results = [];
const blockingPromise = ()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        BUGUTILS.blocker(3);
        if(Math.random()<.5){
            return reject('Less than 50%');
        }
        return resolve('Greater than or equal to 50%');

    })
}
const recurseBlockingPromise= (count)=>{
    if(!count || count==0){
        console.log('all done')
    }else{
        recurseBlockingPromise(--count);
        //BUGUTILS.blocker(3);
        blockingPromise()
            .then(r=>{
                results.push(r)
                console.log('promised resolved',r);
            }).catch(e=>{
                results.push(e)
                console.log('promised rejected',e);
            })
    }
}
const BUGUTILS = require('./debug-utils');

console.log('Before')

let p = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    recurseBlockingPromise(3);
    return resolve('All Good')
}).then(r=>{
    console.log('finished no error');
    results.forEach(result=>{
        console.log("\t",result);
    })
    //console.log("\t" ,results.join("\n\t"),"\t");
}).catch(e=>{
    console.log('Finsished with error',e);
}) 

console.log('after')
```

If you run the above code substituting the 'BUGUTILS.blocker(3)' for a synchronous call you will see the chain of events.  The 'After' output statement executes before all the async calls complete - but the script doesn't finish until all the promises have resolved.

Comment: If you're doing synchronous reads, why would you use promises at all?